# Script output to file when using SQL-Developer

Tags: file, scripting, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a `select` query producing a big output and I want to execute it in sqldeveloper, and get all the results into a file.

Sql-developer does not allow a result bigger than 5000 lines, and I have 100 000 lines to fetch...

I know i could use SQL+, but let's assume I want to do this in sqldeveloper.

Comment: I guess Microsoft must be using one of those combo hammer/screwdrivers then. (i.e. their GUIs do it....)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Instead of using *Run Script (F5)*, use *Run Statement (Ctrl+Enter)*.  Run Statement fetches 50 records at a time and displays them as you scroll through the results...but you can save the entire output to a file by right-clicking over the results and selecting *Export Data -> csv/html/etc*.

I'm a newbie SQLDeveloper user, so if there is a better way please let me know.

Comment: Note that it needs a recent enough version. Version 3.0.03 doesn't have an *Export Data* command, while version 3.1.06 does.

Comment: It needs two executions. If your request takes hours you are screwed

Answer (score 9):

This question is really old, but posting this so it might help someone with a similar issue.

You can store your query in a query.sql file and and run it as a script. Here is a sample query.sql:

```
spool "C:\path\query_result.txt";
select * from my_table;
spool off;
```

In oracle sql developer you can just run this script like this and you should be able to get the result in your *query_result.txt* file.

```
@"C:\Path\to\script.sql"
```

Comment: I need csv output but its printing in some other format which is not much readable

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can increase the size of the Worksheet by change the setting Tool-->Preferences - >Database -> Worksheet -> Max rows to print in a script(depends on you).

Answer (score 0):

Mike G answer will work if you only want the output of a **single** statement.

However, if you want the output of a whole sql script with several statements, SQL*Plus reports, and some other output formats, you can use the `spool` command the same way as it is used in SQL*Plus.